# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

I'm getting this error when trying to predict using a model I built in scikit learn. I know that there are a bunch of questions about this but mine seems different from them because I am wildly off between my input and model features. Here is my code for training my model (FYI the .csv file has 45 columns with one being the known value):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.externals import joblib


df = pd.read_csv("Cinderella.csv")


features_df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Overall_Sentiment', 'Word_1','Word_2','Word_3','Word_4','Word_5','Word_6','Word_7','Word_8','Word_9','Word_10','Word_11','Word_1','Word_12','Word_13','Word_14','Word_15','Word_16','Word_17','Word_18','Word_19','Word_20','Word_21','Word_22','Word_23','Word_24','Word_25','Word_26','Word_27','Word_28','Word_29','Word_30','Word_31','Word_32','Word_33','Word_34','Word_35','Word_36','Word_37','Word_38','Word_39','Word_40','Word_41', 'Word_42', 'Word_43'], dummy_na=True)

del features_df['Slope']

X = features_df.as_matrix()
y = df['Slope'].as_matrix()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

model = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(
    n_estimators=500,
    learning_rate=0.01,
    max_depth=5,
    min_samples_leaf=3,
    max_features=0.1,
    loss='lad'
)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

joblib.dump(model, 'slope_from_sentiment_model.pkl')

mse = mean_absolute_error(y_train, model.predict(X_train))

print("Training Set Mean Absolute Error: %.4f" % mse)

mse = mean_absolute_error(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
print("Test Set Mean Absolute Error: %.4f" % mse)
```

Here is my code for the actual prediction using a different .csv file (this has 44 columns because it doesn't have any values):

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import pandas


model = joblib.load('slope_from_sentiment_model.pkl')

df = pandas.read_csv("Slaughterhouse_copy.csv")


features_df = pandas.get_dummies(df, columns=['Overall_Sentiment','Word_1', 'Word_2', 'Word_3', 'Word_4', 'Word_5', 'Word_6', 'Word_7', 'Word_8', 'Word_9', 'Word_10', 'Word_11', 'Word_12', 'Word_13', 'Word_14', 'Word_15', 'Word_16', 'Word_17','Word_18','Word_19','Word_20','Word_21','Word_22','Word_23','Word_24','Word_25','Word_26','Word_27','Word_28','Word_29','Word_30','Word_31','Word_32','Word_33','Word_34','Word_35','Word_36','Word_37','Word_38','Word_39','Word_40','Word_41','Word_42','Word_43'], dummy_na=True)

predicted_slopes = model.predict(features_df)
```

When I run the prediction file I get:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 146 and input n_features is 226.
```

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any preprocessing like categorical to numerical, or one-hot encoding etc, should be applied on data before it is split in train and test. Preprocessing like scaling and normalization should be done after the split on the train and use the same scales on test.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is due to the different distinct values in your features where you're generating the dummy values with `get_dummies`.

Let's suppose the `Word_1` column in your training set has the following distinct words: `the, dog, jumps, roof, off`. That's 5 distinct words so pandas will generate 5 features for `Word_1`. Now, if your scoring dataset has a different number of distinct words in the `Word_1` column, then you're going to get a different number of features.

**How to fix:**

You'll want to concatenate your training and scoring datasets using [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.concat.html), apply `get_dummies`, and then split your datasets. That'll ensure you have captured all the distinct values in your columns. Given that you're using two different csv's, you probably want to generate a column that specifies your training vs scoring dataset.

**Example solution:**

```
train_df = pd.read_csv("Cinderella.csv")
train_df['label'] = 'train'

score_df = pandas.read_csv("Slaughterhouse_copy.csv")
score_df['label'] = 'score'

# Concat
concat_df = pd.concat([train_df , score_df])

# Create your dummies
features_df = pd.get_dummies(concat_df, columns=['Overall_Sentiment', 'Word_1','Word_2','Word_3','Word_4','Word_5','Word_6','Word_7','Word_8','Word_9','Word_10','Word_11','Word_1','Word_12','Word_13','Word_14','Word_15','Word_16','Word_17','Word_18','Word_19','Word_20','Word_21','Word_22','Word_23','Word_24','Word_25','Word_26','Word_27','Word_28','Word_29','Word_30','Word_31','Word_32','Word_33','Word_34','Word_35','Word_36','Word_37','Word_38','Word_39','Word_40','Word_41', 'Word_42', 'Word_43'], dummy_na=True)

# Split your data
train_df = features_df[features_df['label'] == 'train']
score_df = features_df[features_df['label'] == 'score']

# Drop your labels
train_df = train_df.drop('label', axis=1)
score_df = score_df.drop('label', axis=1)

# Now delete your 'slope' feature, create your features matrix, and create your model as you have already shown in your example
...
```

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr, Is there any other way to do this? My test data comes in real time and I cannot concatenate it with the training data. I train my classifier, save and load it to apply on the test data.

Comment: @Minu There's no easy way to handle unknown data for scoring. In usual cases, it's up to you how you want to handle scoring data but options are either dropping the data or imputing for the value wasn't seen in the training data. Take a look at [feature hashing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#extracting-features) too.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the method [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028890/7470253) and ended up with hot encoding the label column as well,and in the dataframe it is shown as '**label_test**' and '**label_train**' so just a **heads up** try this post get_dummies:

```
train_df = feature_df[feature_df['label_train'] == 1]
test_df = feature_df[feature_df['label_test'] == 0]
train_df = train_df.drop(['label_train', 'label_test'], axis=1)
test_df = test_df.drop(['label_train', 'label_test'], axis=1)
```

Comment: In the second line, did you mean test_df = feature_df[feature_df['label_test'] == 1] ?

Comment: @ParvathySarat the dummy encoding will be applied to the label which has two levels. The two levels are then converted to columns. Those with train are encoded as 1 and test values with 0. the label_test will have 0 values for all test rows.

Comment: just specify columns for dummies and exclude label if it got there

Answer (score 1):

Below correction to original answer from Scratch'N'Purr would help solve issues one might face using string as value for new inserted column 'label' -
        train_df = pd.read_csv("Cinderella.csv")
        train_df['label'] = 1

```
    score_df = pandas.read_csv("Slaughterhouse_copy.csv")
    score_df['label'] = 2

    # Concat
    concat_df = pd.concat([train_df , score_df])

    # Create your dummies
    features_df = pd.get_dummies(concat_df)

    # Split your data
    train_df = features_df[features_df['label'] == '1]
    score_df = features_df[features_df['label'] == '2]
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of the training data(excluding labels,however) which you fit to the model should be same as the size of the data which you are going to predict

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the Categorical Dtype to apply null values to unseen data.

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

# Create Example Data
train = pd.DataFrame({"text":["A", "B", "C", "D", 'F', np.nan]})
test = pd.DataFrame({"text":["D", "D", np.nan,"B", "E", "T"]})

# Convert columns to category dtype and specify categories for test set
train['text'] = train['text'].astype('category')
test['text'] = test['text'].astype(CategoricalDtype(categories=train['text'].cat.categories))

# Create Dummies
pd.get_dummies(test['text'], dummy_na=True)
```

Output:

```
| A | B | C | D | F | nan |
|---|---|---|---|---|-----|
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0   |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0   |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1   |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0   |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1   |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1   |
```